# $\arg(z) = k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ whenever $\Im(z) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I am unsure if I am doing this correctly or if I am justifying this right. But here is the proposition I am trying to prove, and my attempt.

> Proposition: If $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$ and $\Im(z) = 0$, then $\arg(z) = k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Proof: First, let $z = x + yi$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\Im(z) = 0$, then this implies that $y = 0$. So we have $z = x + 0i = x$.

On the complex plane, we have a radius of $x$ because
\begin{equation*}
|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + 0^2} = x
\end{equation*}
also, we must have an angle, which can either be positive or negative, except for 0, since if $x = 0$, then we would have $z = 0 + 0i \notin \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$. So it is either the case that $x$ lies on the positive $\Re$ axis or the negative $\Re$ axis.

- If $x$ lies on the positive $\Re$ axis, then $\theta = 0\pi$,
- If $x$ lies on the negative $\Re$ axis, then $\theta = \pi$.

If we keep on rotating the terminal arm between the positive and negative $\Re$ axes, eventually, we will end up with
\begin{equation*}
\arg(z) = \theta = k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation*}
as required.

I am not sure if this is enough to justify why $\arg(z) = k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so would appreciate some assistance or advice. Thanks.

Comment: $
z \neq 0,\;\Im (z) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \Im (\left| z \right|(\cos (\arg z) + i\sin (\arg z))) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \sin (\arg z) = 0
$

Comment: Sorry, not my specialization: what does $\mathfrak{I}$ denote?

Comment: @cluelessmathematician Imaginary part, produced by \Im. Similarly the real part is \Re, i.e., $\Re$.

Comment: @cluelessmathematician he imaginary part of its argument. So $\Im(z) = y$ when $z=x+iy$ is a complex number.

Comment: And if (like me) you don't like the $\Im$ symbol, use `\operatorname{Im}(z)`, which produces $\operatorname{Im}(z)$.

Comment: Oh, thanks everyone! Good to know; I was only aware of $\operatorname{Im}(\cdot)$ until now. (Thanks @MartinR for the latex tip!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your justification is correct. However its a lot easier to prove it using the polar form of complex numbers:

$$z=|z|e^{i\theta}=|z|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$

as noted by @Gary in the comments.

Comment: This is indeed a lot easier than what I have put down. Thank you for the help!